# Pyspark Structured Streaming continuous vs processingTime triggers

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I've been looking into using triggers for a streaming job, but the differences between Continuous trigger vs processingTime trigger are not clear to me.

As far as I've read on different sites:

1. continuous is just an attempt to make the streaming almost real-time instead of micro-batch based (using much lower latency of 1ms).
2. As of the time of writing this question, only supports a couple of sources and sinks like Kafka.

Are these two points the only differences between the two triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty much right Structured Streaming continuous got added in order to respond to low latency needs by achieving near-real-time processing using a continuous query, unlike the old batch way where the latency is depending on processing time and the batch job duration (aka micro-batch query)

[the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) are pretty useful to get more in-depth.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure I got it right. I read the docs, but thought there was no way that was the only difference.